# List participant IDs who didn't meet the criteria

Tags: r

I am trying to get a list of participants ID and also their % of responses that they didn't meet the criteria.

My data short version looks like this (data name: MyData):

```
structure(list(ID = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L
), .Label = c("rladb11", "rladb7"), class = "factor"), blocknum = c(1L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L), latency = c(322L, 277L, 243L, 188L, 
642L, 155L, 122L, 233L, 280L, 142L, 834L, 134L, 744L, 557L, 523L, 
432L, 524L, 534L, 476L, 533L, 967L, 476L, 523L, 555L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-24L))
```

We need to exclude participants whose data have more than 10% of "too fast" responses (<300ms). We have variables - ID, blocknum, and latency (speed).

So, maybe the expected results would be (with the provided data) like:

1. a list of participant ID and their proportion of response/data <300ms.

```
1. rladb7    0.90
```

or if option 1 is impossible,
2.just list of participants ID

```
rladb7
```

I have been trying to do this by step by step and using by group_by function but it doesn't seem to show the correct number.

Here is the code I have tried and the results:

```
MyData %>% summarise(length(which(MyData$latency<300)))

  <fct>                                            <int>
1 rladb11                                             9   (<< they are somehow put the total number for both)
2 rladb7                                              9

SpeedCount <- length(which(MyData$latency<300))
SpeedProp <- SpeedCount/nrow(MyData)

[1] 0.375 (<<same as above--this is a proportion of all the fast responses from all the participants out of all the responses from all the participants)
```

Which is not quite right. I am not sure how to do the both jobs (# of responses that were <300ms & proportion of those fast responses out of each participants' all responses) together and this is what I expected to happen respectively:

```
  <fct>                    <int>
1 rladb11                    9             .90   
2 rladb7                     0             .00
```

Untimately, I probably would want to see those who didn't meet the criteria (more than 10% responses are <300ms), so like this:

```
  <fct>                    <int>
1 rladb11                    9             .90
```

or the one I listed above (list of participants ID and %, list of participants IDs, both of which who didn't meet the criteria)

Is there any best solution to get the list of those who didn't meet the criteria?

Thank you!

Comment: your dput structure is not complete

Comment: Without the full `dput`, others cannot reconstruct your dataset

Comment: @akrun Sorry somehow the toppart was cut there. It's there now! Thanks!

Comment: can you please check my solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can do a group by `mean`

```
library(dplyr)
MyData %>% 
     group_by(ID) %>% 
     summarise(Prop = mean(latency <300)) %>%
     filter(Prop > 0)
```

Comment: This works perfectly! Thanks so much! I just changed the last one filter (Prop > 0) to filter (Prop > 0.1) so that they only list those proportion is more than 10%!